# Efficient way to delete elements in one numpy array from another

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

What is the best way to delete the elements from one numpy array in another? Essentially I'm after `np.delete()` where the order of the arrays doesn't matter.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,1,3])
print a
b = np.array([4,1,2,5,2,3])
b = np.delete(b, a) # doesn't work as desired
print b # want [4,5,2]
```

Iterating over the elements of `a` is very slow for large arrays.

Comment: Why do you want `[4,5,2]`? `2` is also in `a`, so it should be removed and `b` would be `[4,5]`.

Comment: @Evert I am trying to only delete the first instance of the element in `a`. As written `a` has two `2`'s.

Comment: So if `a = [2,2,1,3]`, `b == [4,5]`? What if `a = [2,2,2,1,3]`? Your case is too unspecific as it currently stands.

Comment: @Evert Yes, in your first case I would want `b == [4,5]`. In the second case I already know that `a` only contains elements within `b`.

Comment: @JohnCrow Would `a` have duplicate values too like : `a = [2,2,1,3]`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes it could

Comment: Doesn't the docs for `np.delete` make it clear that it deletes by index, not value?  Even the Python `del` is by index.  It's `list.remove` that works by value.

Comment: Just curious if you were able to test out the posted approaches on your large arrays?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for the reminder. I have changed the accepted answer to yours since it was over 2 minutes faster per array than the other solution, although they both work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JohnCrow That's Awesome! Appreciate you getting back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `sorting` -

```
def remove_first_match(a,b):
    sidx = b.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    unqb, idx = np.unique(b[sidx],return_index=1)
    return np.delete(b,sidx[idx[np.in1d(unqb,a)]])
```

Sample runs -

```
In [177]: a = np.array([2,1,3])
     ...: b = np.array([4,1,2,5,2,3,2,3])
     ...: 

In [178]: remove_first_match(a,b)
Out[178]: array([4, 5, 2, 2, 3])

In [179]: a = np.array([2,2,1,3])
     ...: b = np.array([4,5])
     ...: 

In [180]: remove_first_match(a,b)
Out[180]: array([4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.argmax` to find the first True element along a set of rows or columns. So, for example, you can do a broadcasted version of this operation this way:

```
>>> a = np.array([2,1,3])
>>> b = np.array([4,1,2,5,2,3])
>>> np.delete(b, np.argmax(b == a[:, np.newaxis], axis=1))
array([4, 5, 2])
```

Of course, as with many numpy vectorized operations, the speed comes at the cost of allocating an array of size `len(a) * len(b)`, so depending on your inputs this may not be appropriate.