# Python numpy array row extraction based on another's array column - faster solution required

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, masking

Two 2D numpy arrays are given (arr_all and arr_sub) whereas the second is a random subset of the first. I need to get the rows of the first one (arr_all) that are not included in the second one (arr_sub) based on an ID in one column that exist in both arrays.
e.g.:

```
arr_all = array([[ x,  y,  z,  id_1],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_2],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_3],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_4],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_5]])

arr_sub = array([[ x,  y,  z,  id_1],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_2],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_5]])
```

wanted output:

```
arr_remain = array([[ x,  y,  z,  id_3],
#        [x,  y,  z,  id_4]])
```

A working solution would be:

```
list_remain = []
for i in range(len(ds_all)):
if ds_all[i][3] not in ds_trees[:,3]:
    list_remain.append(ds_all[i])

arr_remain = np.array(list_remain)
```

This solution however is unfortunately only good for a small dataset because of it's horrible slow runtime. Since my original dataset contains over 26 mio rows, this is not sufficient.

I tried to adapt solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402947/remove-row-of-numpy-array-based-on-values-from-two-columns), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427833/deleting-row-in-numpy-array-based-on-condition) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624209/efficient-way-to-delete-elements-in-one-numpy-array-from-another) but I didn't manage to add the check if the ID exist in the other arrays column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
arr_remain = arr_all[~np.in1d(arr_all[:,-1], arr_sub[:,-1])]
# or arr_remain = arr_all[~np.isin(arr_all[:,-1], arr_sub[:,-1])]
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
array([['x', 'y', 'z', 'id_3'],
       ['x', 'y', 'z', 'id_4']], dtype='<U4')
```

Comment: thanks a lot! This is way faster. Just one note, my IDE complained about `in1d` and preferred `isin`. Seems to be the more recent solution for this task.